# Hardware to get a Bluetooth heart rate signal output as a pulse train?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, heartrate

A while ago I successfully used a Sparkfun Polar Heart Rate Monitor Interface ([SEN-08661](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/8661)) to convert a 'Spirit' cross trainer to pick up the Bluetooth signal from my Polar H10 chest strap instead of needing to use their proprietary wireless chest strap. (This was so I could use just one strap for both my phone and the machine).

The SEN-08661 interface board, often used with Arduino or Raspberry pi systems, receives the Bluetooth HR signal from the chest strap and outputs a simple 5v pulse for each beat, which I fed into the training machine in place of the receiver that was in there originally.

I now want to repeat this with a Lifefitness R1 recumbent bike but unfortunately it seems the SEN-08661 board is no longer available anywhere.

Does anyone know of a similar development board that I could use instead to pick up a Bluetooth HR signal from a Polar strap and output a pulse train?

*Every search I do brings up loads of Bluetooth HR **monitors** but no Bluetooth HR **receivers**.*

I realise this is not really a programming question but I'm hoping some programmers might know where to get the hardware (in the UK) from which to get the signal to process using programming!